# How to get Textbox border if the text in textbox is moving to next page in ssrs

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

[image]The textbox data is going to next page. I need to get border at bottom for textbox in 3rd page and border at top for textbox in 4th page. I don't want to use KEEP IT TOGETHER and BODY BORDER of ssrs report

Answer (score 1):

In SSRS 2008 and 2012 you can conditionally set the `border style` property by using an expression.

First, you have to access to the `PageNumber` Global variable of the report. However you cannot access to this variable from body but only from Page Header and Page Footer. There is a workaround for access it from wherever of your report though.

Go to `Report menu`, `Report Properties...` and `Code` Tab

[image]

Put the following code

```
Function PageNumber() As String    
    Return Me.Report.Globals!PageNumber    
End Function
```

[image]

Now you can access page number in order to conditionally set the border style property.

In the textbox properties, Border property put the below expressions.

[image]

For bottom border in 3rd page use this expression in the `Bottom` property:

```
=IIF(Code.PageNumber = 3,"Solid","None")
```

For top border in 4th page use in the `Top` property:

```
=IIF(Code.PageNumber = 4,"Solid","None")
```

Now the textbox border will appear on bottom in the 3rd page and top on 4th.

Let me know if this was helpful.

Comment: Thanks for answering this. But I'm not getting margin as I mentioned in question and also this expression have issue. when i give this expression. It removes the textbox bottom margin in  4th page and top margin in 3rd page as we are giving condition as page number.

Comment: @AlexMathew edit your question to include a screenshot of the result you are getting. Note my textbox doesn't have any border except at bottom in the third page and top in the fourth. If you want to have border in every side put `Solid` value.

Comment: sorry for late reply.. I want to get line in that red textbox areas. how to get. If content is less textbox will be with in page. when content is more it will go to next page then this issue will get.